# Link between group velocity and Poynting vector EM?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, velocity, poynting-vector

Why poynting vector and group velocity have the same direction?

In isotropic medium is obvious but in anisotropic medium it is more difficult to evaluate

Comment: check [Relation between the Poynting and Group Velocity Vectors of Electromagnetic Waves in a Bi-Gyrotropic Medium](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S106422692107007X) article. It may help you.